# NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.log()Lakka/event/LoggingAdapter

Tags: java, scala, akka

When I start a simple `akka-http-server`, I get an exception. I searched all over the internet and found two solutions which are not working for me:

1. Mixing scala versions.(I had check my pom 2.11 scala without mix)
2. Change scala actor version.(I tried almost ten versions with 2.11 scala)

I have no idea how to resolve this problem, kindly tell me how to resolve it.

```
application.conf
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
  }
}

main class
package com.akkademo;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("akkademo", ConfigFactory.load());
        Config config = actorSystem.settings().config();
        actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(AkkademoDb.class), "akkademo-db");
    }
}

pom.xml
     <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
            <scala>2.11</scala>

            <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
            <akka.version>2.4.14</akka.version>
            <akka.remote>2.3.6</akka.remote>
            <akka.compat>0.7.0</akka.compat>
            <akka.test>2.5.9</akka.test>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>RELEASE</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
                <artifactId>akka-testkit_${scala}</artifactId>
                <version>${akka.test}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
                <artifactId>akka-remote_${scala}</artifactId>
                <version>${akka.remote}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-java8-compat_${scala}</artifactId>
                <version>${akka.compat}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
                <artifactId>akka-actor_${scala}</artifactId>
                <version>${akka.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
                <artifactId>akka-slf4j_${scala}</artifactId>
                <version>${akka.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                <version>${scala.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>aliyun</id>
                <name>aliyun</name>
                <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.log()Lakka/event/LoggingAdapter;
>             at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:128)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>             at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:32)
>             at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>             at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:27)
>             at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:38)
>             at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:38)
>             at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
>             at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:38)
>             at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree1$1(ActorSystem.scala:620)
>             at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.(ActorSystem.scala:613)
>             at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
>             at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:119)
>             at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.create(ActorSystem.scala:67)
>             at akka.actor.ActorSystem.create(ActorSystem.scala)
>             at com.akkademo.Main.main(Main.java:15)

Comment: which jdk are you using? and what about sbt version?

Comment: i used jdk8 and sbt version 4 @RamanMishra

Comment: try downgrading sbt version it should work

Comment: @RamanMishra i am sorry but actually i didn't install sbt and did not configure sbt.i just found a sbt.xml in .idea document and it's content as below :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ScalaSbtSettings">
    <option name="customVMPath" />
  </component>
</project>

Comment: Do you have project/build.properties? If you have than you will see there sbt= version change it I think there is compatibility issue with scala 2.11.x and sbt version @yimkong

Comment: And sbt version can’t be 4 latest is 1.1.x

Comment: @RamanMishra my mistake,i thought the sbt.xml 's <project version> as sbt's version...and i don't have project/build.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is propably caused by using different minor versions of `akka-remoting` and the core `akka-actor` package.

Set the `akka.version` and `akka.remote` property to the same value. The current release is `2.5.19`.